# React Native - Text ignore line breaks

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have the following text:

```
const text = "Hello\nworld";
```

And I am putting it inside the following component

```
 <Text
    numberOfLines={1}
    ellipsizeMode="tail"
    style={[styles.lastMessageText, { color: colors.backdrop }]}
 >
     {text}
 </Text>


...
lastMessageText: {
    maxWidth: "35%",
    fontFamily: "OpenSans",
    fontSize: 12.5,
}
```

How can I ignore the line break? I mean, write the full text in a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Regex:

`{ text.replace(/\n/g, '') }`